# Regularity of $\sigma$-finite measure pushforwarded by completion

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure defined on borel subsets of $X$. Let $i \colon X \to \hat{X}$ be an isometry on image, where $\hat{X}$ is a complete metric space with $i[X]$ being dense in $\hat{X}$. Let $\hat{\mu} = i_\# \mu$ be a pushforward measure on $\hat{X}$.

We can view $\hat{\mu}$ in two ways: either as a measure defined on borel subsets of $\hat{X}$, or as a measure defined on the family $\{ B \subseteq \hat{X} \mid i^{-1}[B] \text{ is borel in }X\}$. On borel subsets of $\hat{X}$, this measure is borel regular, because $\hat{\mu}$ is $\sigma$-finite, as $\mu$ was $\sigma$-finite.
I would like to know whether it is also borel regular as a measure on the latter family.

---

I'm also interested in a possibly weaker property. I know that $\hat{\mu}$ as a measure on the latter family satisfies:
$$ \hat{\mu} \left( \hat{X} \setminus i[X] \right) = \mu( \emptyset) = 0,$$
but, $\hat{X} \setminus i[X]$ need not be a borel subset of $\hat{X}$. Is there a borel  subset $E$ of $\hat{X}$ such that $\hat{X} \setminus i[X]  \subseteq E$ and $\hat{\mu}(E) = 0$?

Comment: Perhaps related: "image measure catastrophe"